# releasing objects when using ARC

Tags: iphone, profiling, automatic-ref-counting, instruments, memory-leaks

While testing the app I am developing I bumped into this issue, which I'd like to discuss.
I've got a class that needs to receive a message from a server and needs to relay the message to a view. This is how I do it:

```
- (void) onMessage:(DFTopicMessage *) message {    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     postNotificationName:@"serverMessage" 
     object:message];
}
```

The class does not do anything else with the message. When I profile with Instruments -> Leaks, this line of code is flagged as a potential leak. What I understand the problem is, is that message is allocated, used and never released. The first strange thing is that I am using ARC in my project and would thus expect the OS to release the var automatically, but that is obviously not the case (then, why does it not release the var?). In any way, I started thinking how to avoid this leak. Simply setting message to nil, such as in :

```
- (void) onMessage:(DFTopicMessage *) message {    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     postNotificationName:@"serverMessage" 
     object:message];
      message = nil;
}
```

won't prevent the leak. I found a solution in making message an ivar and using accessors like this:

```
@interface myClass()
@property(nonatomic) DFTopicMessage *message;
@end

@implementation myClass {
@synthetize message;
    ....
   - (void) onMessage:(DFTopicMessage *) msg {
        [self setMessage:msg];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"serverMessage" 
        object:[self message]];

    }
}
```

Now if I profile with the method below, Instruments -> Leak will no longer flag this as a potential leak. My question is: is this the only solution to kind of forcing releasing a var when using ARC?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you absolutely certain ARC is enabled? is `[msg retain]` a compiler error in that file?

Comment: I suspect that Instruments just gives a false positive here... Your "solution" isn't one, however: You just store an additional reference to `message`, thus tricking Instruments into thinking that the object still is needed. You don't actually release `message` this way (but that shouldn't be necessary anyway).

Comment: Thanks both for your comments.
@BJ Homer: I'm totally sure I am using ARC, [msg release] gives an error about explicitly releasing vars when using ARC.

Comment: @MrMage: yes -- making the var an ivar does store an additional reference to message. However, by using accessors I make sure I don't loose the pointer to the cell, and that seems to allow proper automatic release with ARC. At least, this is what Instruments states.

Comment: But aren't ivars weak references by default?

Comment: I would imagine you should declare them as weak, in order for them to be considered so...?

Comment: @MrMage No, any object variable under ARC is `__strong` be default. @Diferdin Did you walk up the call stack for `onMessage:` and ensure that the problem is not there where the message is being generated?

Comment: The code looks fine. Which type of object is reported to be leaked by Instruments?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this problem? I was thinking that you might have references to your message in other parts of your code.

Comment: @Resh32 the answer kind of was in the question, but my question as to whether that is the only way is still open. It looks like that is the only way, so I'll probably close the question...

Answer (score 0):

When you Analyze the project, does it flag this method as a possible leak as well?( I suspect not).

Are you sure that the leak that Instruments is detecting is this message object? If it is, it looks like it must be a false positive, because, with ARC enabled, this should NOT be leaking.